# --replace \"css/*.css\" \"!css/*.rtl*.css\" \"!css/*.min.css\""

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, scripting, package.json

I would like to clarify regarding this line of code?

```
" --replace \"css/*.css\" \"!css/*.rtl*.css\" \"!css/*.min.css\"",
```

I have read some documentation but I'm not really sure if i clearly understand it.


Based on what i understand, this line of code is replacing all .css file extension inside the css folder, but exclude all .rtl and .min.css inside the css folder?

```
\"!css/*.rtl*.css\" \"!css/*.min.css\"",
```

Im confused on this part if this ! symbol is exluding .rtl .css file and .min.css file?



This is the full script that im currently working on.

```
"css-postcss": "postcss --config src/build/postcss.config.js --replace \"css/*.css\" \"!css/*.rtl*.css\" \"!css/*.min.css\"",
```

Please Enlighten my knowledge.

Thank you!